# Convert AST nodes string to groovy code

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create groovy code using AstBuilder, but afterwards, I'd like to see how the actual groovy code would look like.
Is it possible to convert AST nodes' toString output like this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement@5b7a5baa[
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement@776aec5c[
expression:org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression@1d296da[
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression@7c7a06ec[
variable: cl]("=" at 2:17:  "=" )org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression@13c9d689[
]{ org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement@75d4a5c2[
] }]]]
```

back into groovy code?

Comment: Have you checked the `text` property on the outer-most `ASTNode` (ex. the BlockStatement)? I suspect that's being set by the compiler, so in the case of creating nodes by hand without source code, it may not work. But according to the Groovy console AST Browser, the `text` property represents the `ASTNode`'s source code.

Comment: Unfortunately `text` property is not implemented consistently for all classes. For example `IfStatement` doesn't implement it at all and it returns a message that the method was not implemented. Some other classes also don't return very helpful message, so you can't just invoke `getText()` on the outer-most object.

Comment: Nothing that I have found, but it's like the Matrix... after a while, you just start to "see" what the generated code looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my favourite code snippet which I use when I work with AST transformations:

```
java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor visitor = new groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor(writer);
visitor.visitClass(node); // replace with proper visit****
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

It will provide almost correct Groovy code from it. It's still not 100% correct (I mean, if you will compile it back then it might not compile), but more than enough for debugging.

Example in MacroGroovy:

https://github.com/bsideup/MacroGroovy/blob/950193cb2d12443bf0c7b7af9635f24712d3bad0/src/main/groovy/ru/trylogic/groovy/macro/MacroTransformation.java#L58

Answer (score 0):

The class `AstNodeToScriptVisitor` is now part of the groovy sub project groovy-console package. Here you found now the class to generate code from an AST node.

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def visitor = new groovy.console.ui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor(writer)
visitor.visitClass(demoClass)
println writer
```

In your project you can import this package for example via Gradle.

```
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-console', version: '3.0.11'
```